# Python Google cloud function and JavaScript Post request

Tags: javascript, python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Python cloud function with the following code:

```
import requests
import json

def make_func(request):

     if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
          headers = {
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
               'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
               'Content-Type': '*',
               'Content-Length': "3000"
          }

          return ('', 204, headers)

     request_json = request.get_json()
     print(request_json) #THIS SHOWS "NONE" IN THE LOGS

     domain = request_json['domain']

     headers = {
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
               'Content-Type': '*',
               'Content-Length': "3000"

     }    
     return (str(domain)), 200, headers)
```

I want to sent json data with a JavaScript xhr post request to this function. The JS code is the following:

```
const data = {
  domain : "test.com"
}

var domain = "blabla.com";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', domain, true);
xhr.send(data);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var result = xhr.responseText;
     alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  }
}
```

If I looking into the logs of my GCF and I print the request, it says "None". It can't find the "domain" variable in the request variable in python. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the header:

```
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
 xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```